# ThreeJS Cube texture strange visual

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having a strange visual effect (don't know how to call it) in my project. I've made a cube and made it possible to rotate. Below I got the code which creates the cube.

Also see the image. If I upscale my `segmentsWidth` and `segmentsHeight` it's kinda gonna look better on the side, but on the front the lines will not be straight. The image is made with the code shown below. What I would like to see is the lines at the front straight and side ways it should not have a V in it.

If I have the `overdraw = false` than I will see white lines which I don't want but don't got a messy picture. But when I set it to true I will have a messy picture.

Is this possible?

[image: Example doors]

```
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.y = 150;
    camera.position.z = 250;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Cube

    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 200, 8, 1, 1 );

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xefefef }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xefefef }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xefefef }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xefefef }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/door.jpg'),
            overdraw: false
        }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/door.jpg'),
            overdraw: false
        })
    ]));
    cube.position.y = 150;
    scene.add( cube );
```

Comment: maybe up the number of polygons : THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 200, 8, 4, 4 );

Comment: That does make it better, but how more i put the the blury the front will be. It's a straght lines which will have a lot of S lines in it.

Comment: this remember me the PS1 graphics :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well-known issue with `CanvasRenderer`.

An excellent description of the issue can be found in the last half of [this post](http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=2120).

Your best solution is to increase the tessellation of your geometry.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 200, 8, 2, 2, 2 );
```

P.S. Notice there are 6, not 5, args to this constructor.

EDIT: updated for three.js r.67

Comment: Yes today I already change to WebGLRenderer and than it's fixed, but I need a backup for browsers that don't support WebGL and wanted to know if there was a possibility is would be better rendered. So I will accept this as the right answer since there isn't any improvement to get from canvas.