# Three.JS with Canvas Renderer, broken Textures

Tags: three.js

If you look at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Wireframe.html without enable webgl, you see a white diagnal line crossing the texture. This happens only in CanvasRenderer. Does anyone knows how can this be fixed.

[image: Diagnal line crossing the texture]

When WebGL is enabled, the output is correct, like below:[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagonal lines are an artifact of `CanvasRenderer`. You can compensate for them by setting `material.overdraw = 0.5`, or some number between 0 and 1.

The distortion in the checkerboard pattern when using `CanvasRenderer` is explained in the answer to [ThreeJS Cube texture strange visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709866/threejs-cube-texture-strange-visual).

UPDATED: `Material.overdraw` used to be a boolean. It is now a number.

three.js r.61