# Threejs UV mapping distortion

Tags: three.js

I have following problem image gets distorted along the face side (red line).
I have a few layers like this on each I have the same distortion.
I have double checked UV mapping and both faces have the same 2 UV coordinates for same 2 points. I would paste some code but it is a bit complex UV calculation. I am trying to see if somebody had a similar problem.

[image]

Uv mapping for this part (Red line matches picture above)
[image]

Here is the code for UV calculation but you probably wont be able to find an error there.

```
calculateNewUvMapping(vertices: Array<Vector3>): Array<Vector2> {
const orderedVertices = _.clone(vertices).reverse();
const newArray: Array<Vector2> = new Array<Vector2>();

const startV3 = orderedVertices[0];
const endV3 = orderedVertices[orderedVertices.length - 1];

const start = new Vector2(startV3.x, startV3.z);
const end = new Vector2(endV3.x, endV3.z);

// Distance between two vertices on scale from 0 to 1
const distanceAlpha = 1 / (orderedVertices.length - 1);

newArray.push(start);
for (let i = 1; i < orderedVertices.length - 1; i++) {
  const newUv = new Vector2();
  const interpolationValue = distanceAlpha * i;
  newUv.lerpVectors(start, end, interpolationValue);
  newArray.push(newUv);
}
newArray.push(end);

return newArray;
}
```

EDIT: Its not normals calculation.

Comment: It is 3D projection we also exported model and opened it in blender uv mapping is same there so we are unsure whats wrong :). Also this bottom romb part is flat two faces are connected but they are forming a plane

Comment: Sorry i meant it is a 3d model not projection

Comment: I am calculating geometry on my own i am creating spherical-ish model and calculating faces and UV

Comment: @DživoJelić Is this your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880015/three-js-with-canvas-renderer-broken-textures

Comment: @WestLangley actually its this and its pretty decent answer but i am going to need some time to try it out. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/148082/how-can-i-fix-zig-zagging-uv-mapping-artifacts-on-a-generated-mesh-that-tapers/148102#148102?newreg=abe0d6aa9a6242ebb62331e4895228dd

Comment: You sure it's not something simple like a missing perspective correction hint for texture rendering?

Comment: @FrederikDeRuyck can you give me an example ? Not quite sure what you mean

Comment: Could it be a similar problem to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242507/perspective-correct-texturing-of-trapezoid-in-opengl-es-2-0